# Can I download data collected by Azure Application Insights (events list)?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Viewing Event Application Insight logs in browser on portal.azure.com is highly impractical. I want to download those logs as, for example, Excel file.

There actually is an "Export" button, but what it does is: it shows how many times one event was fired and there are no event details here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can continuously export data to Azure blob storage as described in that part of the documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-telemetry/

From there, you can do whatever you want with this captured data: download it, query it from Azure HDInsight, Azure Data Lake Analytics, a Web Job in Azure Web App and so on.

Comment: Hi, if you consider that answers your question, can you check it as an answer? Thanks!