# Export Azure application Insight log files to Azure Data Lake storage

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-lake

I am beginner of the azure portal , I configured the Azure Application insight in front-end side (Angular 2) and Back-end side  (Asp.net core)

I can track my application log file through azure application insight,and export the xls sheet also http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/12/04/exporting-application-insights-data-to-excel-its-just-a-single-click/ ,But i need to store all my log file into azure data lake storage for the Backup tracking purpose

I need to debug the issue on my application while facing issues.but i got the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-code-sample-export-sql-stream-analytics and [Can I download data collected by Azure Application Insights (events list)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357904/can-i-download-data-collected-by-azure-application-insights-events-list,for) continues export for sql,blob storage,i dont want unwanted storage for storing my data in azure resources.

So If there is any way for connect application insight to Azure Data lake through connector or plugins.IF its could you please share me the link.

Thank you..

Answer (score 4):

**Automatic**

If you [export the events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-telemetry) to azure blob storage you can do multiple things:

- Use [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-datalake-connector) to copy the data from blob storage to Azure Data Lake
- Use [AdlCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-azure-storage-blob) to copy the data from blob storage to Azure Data Lake
- Write [an U-Sql job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-data-lake-tools-get-started) to copy the data to Azure Data Lake

**Manual**

To manually place exported Application Insights data (in .xls format) you can [use the portal to upload the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-portal#a-nameuploaddataaupload-data-to-azure-data-lake-store-account) to Azure Data Lake.

If you need to have more control about the exported data you can use [Application Insights Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-tour) to create a query based on the available data and export it to an .xls file.

If course you can also create a small app to export the .xls file to Azure Data Lake if you do not want to upload it using the portal. You can use [the api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-rest-api#upload-data-into-a-data-lake-store-account) for that.

Comment: @Bons Thanks for your Response,At the same time we need to do manual functionality.there have a any way to streaming copy to azure blob storage to azure data lake..

Comment: so if I understand correctly you need both. Like automatic export to data like (you can use the info in my answer for that) AND manual export to data lake? Is that correct?

Comment: No.still i am not worked on export i will check that then i will post on that.Thanks for the Response.

Comment: Great. Please accept my answer if it is any good to you so others can use the same information

Comment: Yes Its working For Me thanks @bons Then i add the Pipeline For the File copy wizared using in Azure dataFactory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-copy-data-wizard-tutorial